# Configuring a program to run as a service

Tags: printer, windows-server-2003

I have just purchased a HP Color LaserJet CM2320fxi MRP combined printer/scanner/fax. I have installed the software on a Windows Server 2003 machine. However when I log out of the server and try to scan using the machine I get a connection error, as far as I can see this is due to the requirement for HP Toolbox FX to be running when the scanner is being used.

Does anyone know of a way to get HP Toolbox FX to run all the time, like making it run as a service. I want users to just press a few buttons on the machine and their scans appear on the network shares, not have to log on to a computer and access special software.

Anyone able to help or give me any ideas on this?

Thanks

Comment: Better on Server Fault?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [FireDaemon](http://www.firedaemon.com)?

You can also have a go at doing this yourself with Srvany.exe and Instsrv.exe as per [How To Run Automation Manager as a Windows NT Service - KB193238](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;193238) - I think this still appiles to W2K3.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to the startup folder